# Filtrar postagem do wordpress utilizando REGEXP para postagens que não sejam de A a Z

Tags: php, wordpress, regex

Gostaria de saber como posso realizar um processo de filtragem completo das postagens do wordpress utilizando expreções regulares, de forma que só mostre toda ou qualquer postagem que não tenha como caractere inicial de A a Z, como numeros, Caracteres especiais, letras em japonês, e qualquer outro tipo de caractere estrangeiro, ou simbolo da web.

O meu código abaixo filtra numeros e alguns caracteres especiais, mais não esta filtrando como relatei todos os tipos de postagem gostaria de saber como posso emplementar essa função ao código abaixo no campo REGEXP.

```
if (isset( $_GET['letra'] )) {

if ($_GET['letra'] == '0-9') {
$postids=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT   ID
FROM     $wpdb->posts
WHERE    $wpdb->posts.post_title REGEXP '^[0-9\$\@\!\?\%\-]'
ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title")); 
}
else {
$first_char = $_GET['letra'];
$postids=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT   ID
FROM     $wpdb->posts
WHERE    SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) = %s
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_title",$first_char));
}
query_posts(array(
    'post__in'        => $postids,
    'posts_per_page'  => $porPagina,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
    'paged'           => $paginador,
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'post_type'       => 'media',
    'meta_key'        => 'modulo_da_media',
    'meta_value'      => 'modo-01',
    'order'           => $ordr,
    'orderby'         => $orde
)); } else {

query_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'=> $porPagina,
    'paged'         => $paginador,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'media',
    'meta_key'      => 'modulo_da_media',
    'meta_value'    => 'modo-01',
    'order'         => $ordr,
    'orderby'       => $orde
));
}
```

Comment: Pode usar `^[^a-zA-Z]` - só que aí vai pegar os que começam com qualquer coisa que não seja uma letra de "a" a "z" (qualquer coisa mesmo: espaço, pontuação, letras de outros alfabetos, emojis, etc) - lembrando que não leva em conta letras acentuadas.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, esta funcionando agora perfeitamente da forma que eu necessito.